# When should I override debugFillProperties in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why should I use **debugFillProperties** in the stateful widget in Flutter? I have seen Some flutter Built-in stateful widgets Like **Slider** using this method.

I went through Flutter Docs given [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/debugFillProperties.html). I'm still not able to understand the practical usage of **debugFillProperties**. When or why use it?

I tried It in My example code, Still Not able to understand. I did not find any docs or relevant information was found about this method in Flutter.

```
  double? min;
  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    print("--------------Debug-------------");
    properties.add(IntProperty('min', min, defaultValue: 5, ifNull: "nulll"));
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By overriding the **debugFillProperties** function, we can show the current value of a variable (state) in the Details Tree

example:
without overriding this method:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late MyColorScheme _myColorScheme;
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myColorScheme = MyColorScheme(Colors.black, Colors.white);
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

[image]

with overriding this method:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late MyColorScheme _myColorScheme;
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myColorScheme = MyColorScheme(Colors.black, Colors.white);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(IntProperty('_counter', _counter));
    properties.add(
        DiagnosticsProperty<MyColorScheme>('myColorScheme', _myColorScheme));
  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also, the information from [debugFillProperties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget/debugFillProperties.html) will be shown in the output from a [debugDumpApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/debugDumpApp.html) call.

See [Debugging App Programmatically -> Widget Tree section](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/code-debugging#widget-tree) for more details.